# Как объединить 2 Dictionary в один новый?

Tags: c#, словари

Добрый день. Возник дурацкий вопрос:
Есть 2 Dictionary. Нужно получить третий, который будет включать в себя все пары "ключ-значение" из первого и второго. Точно известно, что совпадения ключей в словарях нет.

Пробовал так - не получается.

```
        Markers = new Dictionary<string, string>(CreateCommonMarkers(vm));
        Markers.Concat(UniqueMarkers);
        return Markers;
```

`CreateCommonMarkers` - создается правильно
`UniqueMarkers` - создается правильно 
`Markers` получает первый словарь правильно.
А вот `Concat` не срабатывает. На выходе - дубликат словаря, создаваемого `CreateCommonMarkers(vm)`
Соответственно вопрос: что я сделал не так?

P.S. сделать через foreach я  могу, но может есть менее извращенный способ.

Comment: Concat же возвращает результат, а вы его не читаете.

Comment: Да,уже увидел ошибку. Получается, что я хотел добавить второй словарь к первому, а нужно было создать третий, который будет объединять первые два

Comment: @foxhound, по сути вам нужно просто `return CreateCommonMarkers(vm).Concat(UniqueMarkers);`

Comment: @ Андрей Да, но без .ToDictionary(x=>x); компилятор ругается

Comment: @Андрей Concat вернет IEnumerable, а не IDictionary

Comment: @tym32167, согласен, надо `return CreateCommonMarkers(vm).Concat(UniqueMarkers).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);`

Comment: @Андрей ну то есть то же самое, что у меня в ответе :)

Comment: @tym32167, ну так я свой и не пишу поэтому :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уверены, что совпадений ключей нет, то можно попробовать так:

```
var dict1 = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToDictionary(x=>x);
var dict2 = Enumerable.Range(15,10).ToDictionary(x=>x);
```

Для объединения словарей можно использвать методы Union или Concat. Разница между ними только в том, что Union удаляет доубликаты, что в данном контексте не требуется.     Для маленьких словарей нет разницы, какой из методов использовать, для больших, как мне кажется, Concat будет работать быстрей.

```
var combined_version_1 = dict1.Union(dict2).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
var combined_version_2 = dict1.Concat(dict2).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

Как видно, на входе получается третий словарь, который можно вернуть как результат.

Comment: А почему не просто `Concat`?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста в ответ, что на выходе должен быть НОВЫЙ словарь, с не добавление 2-го к первому.

Comment: @VladD первое что в голову пришло отписал :)

Comment: @foxhound добавил